# How to create an `IpAddr` without knowing the specific IP version?

Tags: rust

I am playing with `Iron`, and I ran into this problem.

```
fn main() {
    let mut router = Router::new();
    let address = "127.0.0.1"; // or maybe "::1/128"
    let port = 3000;
    let ip = std::net::IpAddr::new(address); // does not exist

    Iron::new(router).http((ip, port)).unwrap();
}
```

The `http()` method takes a struct that implements [`ToSocketAddrs`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/trait.ToSocketAddrs.html). `(&str, u16)` implements this trait, but I prefer to verify the validity of user input **before** the `http()` method is called.

I saw that `(std::net::IpAddr, u16)` implements this trait, but I do not know how to build an `IpAddr` “agnostically”: maybe the user wrote an IPv4 address, maybe an IPv6.

Is there a way to create an `IpAddr` from a string only? I think that it is possible because I can give to it a `(&str, u16)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your friend is the [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) trait from the standard library. It abstracts types that can be created from a string. As you can see [`Ipv4Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.Ipv4Addr.html), [`Ipv6Addr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.Ipv6Addr.html) and [`IpAddr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/enum.IpAddr.html) all implement that trait! So you could either write:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

let addr = IpAddr::from_str("127.0.0.1");
```

Or, the slightly more common way, by using the [`str::parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) method:

```
let addr = "127.0.0.1".parse::<IpAddr>();
```

The `from_str()`/`parse()` methods return a `Result` to signal whether or not the string is valid.

Comment: Why those two ways? Is the second more idiomatic?

Comment: @Boiethios `parse()` uses `from_str()` internally. It only exists for convenience: you don't have to import the trait and you often don't have to mention the type name because type inference will do it for you (probably in your case as well). I *think* `parse()` is more idiomatic as in "used more frequently".

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The docs casually mention that `parse()` is used more often than `from_str()`, but don't say why. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#examples-1 I think being a method of str vs importing a trait, and being able to name the type (instead of using type ascription) are exactly the reasons.