# The FromStr trait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to use the Cidr crate, and need to convert strings to CIDRs. But it's not working and I can't figure out why. I think I need to `use` something, but `std::str::FromStr` doesn't help. What's worse is that I don't even know where to look next.

```rust
error[E0599]: no variant named `from_string` found for type `cidr::AnyIpCidr` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:45:30
   |
45 |     let c = cidr::AnyIpCidr::from_string(ipstr);
   |             -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             variant not found in `cidr::AnyIpCidr`
```

Comment: Looks like you meant `from_str`?

Comment: tl;dr: try `let c: AnyIpCidr = ipstr.parse();` If `AnyIpCdr` implements `FromStr` it will work.

Comment: Essentially the same or very similar questions regarding `FromStr`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42030345/3650362, https://stackoverflow.com/q/48655891/3650362, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23391440/3650362

Comment: @loganfsmyth hit it dead on. I had spent hours using from_string when it should have been from_str.